# unable to ping DNS server in eucalyptus cloud

Tags: dns, eucalyptus

I am installing eucalyptus 4.4.4 on centos 7 and i have done all the installation steps but DNS is still not working. When i using ping to check it is showing error that cannot find service.

Answer (score 0):

To check the status of the eucalyptus dns service you can use:

```
# euserv-describe-services --filter service-type=dns --expert
SERVICE  arn:euca:bootstrap:api.10.117.111.14:dns:api.10.117.111.14.dns/  enabled  21  http://192.168.111.14:8773/services/Dns
```

If the service is not enabled then the most likely reason is that another service is installed and using the dns port.

If the service is enabled then you can check the output using dig:

```
 dig +short ec2.internal @192.168.111.14
192.168.111.14
```

In this example my dns and ec2 (compute) services are on the same host.

If you see a response such as:

```
Warning: query response not set
```

from the dig command then you may not have enabled dns functionality, to check and then enable dns run:

```
# euctl dns.enabled
# euctl dns.enabled=true
```

It is also a good idea to review other setting described in the documentation to verify dns settings:

http://docs.eucalyptus.cloud/eucalyptus/4.4.5/index.html#shared/setting_up_dns.html

Comment: on running euserv-describe-services --filter service -type=dns --expert the output is enabled but on running the second command i.e dig +short ec2.internal @10.99.1.169 output is query response not set'